# What does Cyberpunk mean "in universe"

Tags: cyberpunk, cyberpunk-1988, cyberpunk-2077, cyberpunk-edgerunners

Within the universe of the 1988 role-play game "[Cyberpunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk_(role-playing_game))" and, its canonical extended material, what does it mean when one character describes another character as being "a cyberpunk".

Does it have a clear and definitive meaning, as opposed to describing an aesthetic?

This is specifically about the universe of the game, not the pop culture aesthetic, or cosplay.

Comment: Same thing it means here - like punk, but *cyber*...

Comment: https://bibliocecifi.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/cyberpunk-the-roleplaying-game-of-the-dark-future-r-talsorian-games-inc.pdf

Comment: @Valorum I'm unsure about the [tag:cyberpunk-1988] tag. While it fits the `title-year` scheme for works, the other works in the series also have years in the title: [tag:cyberpunk-2020] and [tag:cyberpunk-2077]. Perhaps we need a [tag:cyberpunk-series] instead?

Comment: @OrangeDog - All of the above are editions of Cyberpunk '88

Comment: @Valorum well no, cyberpunk-2020 is the second edition TTRPG, but cyberpunk-2077 is the computer game

Answer (score 6):

**Hi-tech lowlife**

There is no "the" cyberpunk universe; "cyberpunk" is a tag used to a describe certain style of science fiction. However, the term is often used to describe "hi-tech lowlife" (cyber + punk), and I suspect that this is how it is used in *Cyberpunk 2077*.

Comment: It's a tabletop game. It most definitely has universe. It's famous for it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk_(role-playing_game)

Comment: I though that this would be obvious.

Comment: But apparently it isn’t. Heck, I was around in the 80s and don’t remember that game.

Comment: An anime based on it is trending on Netflix right now, its all over the Internet.

Comment: @AaarghZombies And after watching 10 minutes of the 1st episode of that anime, I was like "nope. not for me".  It seemed frenetic and styled like it came from the 80's (to match the game?)

Comment: @AaarghZombies: When I wrote the answer, the question had no mention of  the role-play game Cyberpunk (with which I am quite familiar"; it just mentioned "the cyberpunk universe" (capitalization). I naturally can't be expected to consider information added AFTER my answer.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen, I said cyberpunk universe, not cyberpunk genre.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: Yes, but "cyberpunk" wasn't capitalized, so I assumed you meant cyberpunk generically, not the specific Cyberpunk game universe.

Answer (score 4):

I've never played the pen & paper game, but "cyberpunk" is mentioned once or twice in the video game. The following conversation can be found on a [shard](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/A_Delamain_Too_Far) in Pacifica:

> PHEA MIZ: oh yeah? wanna bet? ;]
>
> SERGIO CONSONNI: haha but why risk it?
>
> PHEA MIZ: just cuz
>
> PHEA MIZ: THIS CYBERPUNK AINT DEAD YET BABY

Similar to the term "punk", it seems to refer to a movement or possibly a state of mind.

Answer (score 4):

From the Second Edition (Cyberpunk 2020) rulebook:

> *Cyberpunk* comes from two words. *Cyber* -- from the term cybernetic, or a fusion of flesh and machine technology, *Punk* -- from an early 1980's rock music style that epitomised violence, rebellion and social action in a nihilistic way.
>
> [...]
>
> There were three major responses to technoshock. The vast majority of people, their lives uprooted and changed by the advancements, sat passively waiting for their leaders to tell them what to do next. One smaller group tried to turn back the clock, founding the basis of what we call the Neo-Luddite movement. The remaining group -- they decided to hit the future head on. With the old 1980's visionary writings as their guide, they established the movement we now call *Cyberpunk*.
>
> As a *cyberpunk* you grab technology by the throat and hang on. You're not afraid to check out the newest in "enhancements", cybertech and bioengineering. You've got interface plugs in your wrists, weapons in your arms, lasers in your eyes, biochip programs in your brain. You become the car you drive, the gyro you fly, the guns you shoot. You dive headfirst into the Net, using your mind to hurtle at lightspeed all over a vast network of Data Fortresses and Artificial Intelligences. With cyborged fingers you pick computer locks; with enhanced senses, you see into the Future.
>
> *Cyberpunk* is also an attitude. You wear the most "in" clothes, know the right people, and follow the right crowds. You plan your crimes in the most select clubs and bars; your enemies are Corporate armies, cyborg bike gangs, power-armored assassins and computer-wired Netheads. Your weapons are nerve, streetsmarts, bravado and the Minami 10 smartgun on your hip.

So in-Universe it means literally mimicking the cyberpunk genre popularised in the '80s, which conveniently is exactly what it means in real life too.